# Activate Plugin which is in subfolder?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, activation

I try to activate the plugin inside the plugin folder is possible ? I am adding the absolute path of the plugin as something like

I have a folder as main file and subfolder contain another plugin 
Let consider 
plugina.php is in main folder and pluginb.php is in sub folder I want to activate the pluginb.php without moving the path any.

```
<?php
function run_activate_plugin( $plugin ) {
    $current = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
    $plugin = plugin_basename( trim( $plugin ) );

    if ( !in_array( $plugin, $current ) ) {
        $current[] = $plugin;
        sort( $current );
        do_action( 'activate_plugin', trim( $plugin ) );
        update_option( 'active_plugins', $current );
        do_action( 'activate_' . trim( $plugin ) );
        do_action( 'activated_plugin', trim( $plugin) );
    }

    return null;
}
run_activate_plugin( 'plugin/subfolder/plugin.php');

?>
```

When i try the above code `The Plugin has been deactivated due to an error: The plugin does not have a valid header.` This error is appear.
I am not sure i am trying the correct way or is there is someother way to activate the plugin from subfolder.

**EDIT:**

Actually I am trying to add the module in the main plugin for that i try to scan the module folder inside the main plugin file and link that absolute path to the function. But it doesn't work for me return erro as i mentioned above(The Plugin doesn't have valid header information) In the module folder plugin also contain the file header but still it causing the error. :(

Not sure Any suggestion would be great

Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Can you paste in the plugin header? It's the comment block at the top of a plugin to make WordPress aware of the plugin name etc...

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin for some information on how to structure your plugin. In your case, especially check out the File Headers section of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment. I am trying to add the module folder inside the main plugin. Let explain little bit I have the main folder name as mainplugin in that i have sub module plugin which is in module folder. I scanned the module folder and i am trying to activate with above code is get it into error and deactivated.