# How to Overwrite validate_plugin function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, function-exists

How can I overwrite the WordPress `validate_plugin` function. I need to disable that function alone for my plugin, and it should not affect any other plugin.

I don't want the validate_plugin function for my plugin right now, I couldn't find a declared hook, `do_action` or `apply_filter`, within the function in the `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` file.

```
<?php
function run_activate_plugin( $plugin ) {
    $current = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
    $plugin = plugin_basename( trim( $plugin ) );

    if ( !in_array( $plugin, $current ) ) {
        $current[] = $plugin;
        sort( $current );
        do_action( 'activate_plugin', trim( $plugin ) );
        update_option( 'active_plugins', $current );
        do_action( 'activate_' . trim( $plugin ) );
        do_action( 'activated_plugin', trim( $plugin) );
    }

    return null;
}
run_activate_plugin( 'plugin/subfolder/plugin.php');

?>
```

If i activate the plugin from subfolder it got deactivate because of that above function. So that the reason i want to disable the validate_plugin function for my plugin alone.

```
run_activate_plugin( 'plugin/subfolder/plugin.php');
```

Generally run_activate_plugin argument is to be look like

```
run_activate_plugin( 'akismet/akismet.php');
```

But now i am doing activate the plugin from subfolder like this way

```
run_activate_plugin( 'akismet/newfolder/akismet.php');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why `validate_plugin`? All that does is check whether ["the file exists and {@link validate_file() is valid file}."](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L866). I can't imagine why you would not want that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i am trying to activate more than one plugin which means activate another plugin inside the subfolder. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131475/activate-plugin-which-is-in-subfolder  But for some reason i can't able to activate the plugin which is in subfolder when i comment those function in core it working perfect

Comment: I am fairly certain that I have been able to do this before (but not 100% sure :) ). Post some (minimal) code please-- enough that someone could duplicate the issue.

Comment: Much Appreciate your help. I edited the code :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution: generate a backtrace in the function and bail early if called from `validate_active_plugins()`.

```
function action_option_active_plugins( $value, $option ) {

    // Look at the call backtrace and bail early if called from validation function.
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace( 2 ); // Exclude ['object'] and ['args']
    foreach( $backtrace as $frame ) {
        if( $frame['function'] === 'validate_active_plugins' ) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    //Do other stuff with $value...

    return $value;
 }
 add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'wpcom_vip_option_active_plugins', 10, 2 );
```